# MySQL query issue: Can't select columns from another table

Tags: mysql, select

My SQL statement looks like that

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS q.id, q.question, sb.subject, c.chapter, sc.section, p.paragraph 
FROM questions AS q
     , subjects AS sb
     , sections AS sc
     , chapters AS c
     , paragraphs AS p 
WHERE (sb.id=q.subject AND c.id=q.chapter AND sc.id=q.section AND p.id=q.paragraph) AND (q.author_id=1) 
ORDER BY  q.id asc 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

As you see, theese tables related with each other by id. The problem is, I'm getting `subject` column of `questions` table instead of `subject` column of `subjects` table. What am I missing here?

Note

I provided subject as example. Actually all three  sections AS sc, chapters AS c, paragraphs AS p are not working. I'm getting only subject.

Comment: That would mean there's a serious flaw in MySQL. Did you copy the *actual* statement?

Comment: @epic_syntax: 99.9% of the time that someone claims that MySQL is doing something wrong, it turns out that it was actually the programmer that was doing something wrong. I'm not saying that you *haven't* found some strange bug in MySQL - it's certainly possible - but the fact is that it's most likely you've made a stupid mistake. If you are 100% convinced that it is in fact a bug in MySQL, please post some example data that we use to verify that it is indeed a bug.

Comment: With the above said - If both these tables have a subject column, the first question would be "why?", but since they are, perhaps both tables have the same subject?

Comment: @Lieven What do you mean by this?

Comment: @epic_syntax - I'll rephrase, if you copy and paste the statement posted **here**, do you still see the error? Are the subjects from `subjects` and `questions`perhaps the same?

Comment: How are you reading the results? Are you running this in phpMyAdmin, or Workbench, or PHP or what? Can you post the code (if any) that you are using to read and display the results? Maybe the error is there. Also, if you haven't tried running the query in Workbench, try doing that. It will eliminate one possible source of errors.

Comment: @Lieven the problem is, this sql statement generated by very long function (PHP), To modify something, I need to review all function. I provided, exact output of this function

Comment: So have you run this against the database directly, for example in phpMyAdmin?  That's the way to debug it... get it into pure SQL and work it out, then go feed back whatever you discover into the PHP code.

Comment: @epic_syntax - To make an analogy: You are telling your mechanic that your car is broken and you brought your lawnmower for him to look at.

Comment: @BenjaminCox wrote this directly into DB. Same result.

Comment: also show us the result of your own query.. Please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally use JOIN syntax explicitly.  This will sometimes give you better error output, to help track down the issue.

Here's the original, formatted so you can easily see the differences.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS q.id, q.question, sb.subject, c.chapter, sc.section, p.paragraph 
FROM questions AS q, 
     subjects AS sb, 
     sections AS sc, 
     chapters AS c, 
     paragraphs AS p 
WHERE (sb.id=q.subject 
       AND c.id=q.chapter 
       AND sc.id=q.section 
       AND p.id=q.paragraph) 
      AND (q.author_id=1) 
ORDER BY  q.id asc 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

And here's the edited version - notice the WHERE clause parameters that define how the tables hook together have been moved up to the table names list as ON clauses.  This is part of the INNER JOIN syntax, which is:   INNER JOIN  ON .

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS q.id, q.question, sb.subject, c.chapter, sc.section, p.paragraph 
FROM questions AS q
  INNER JOIN subjects AS sb ON sb.id = q.subject
  INNER JOIN sections AS sc ON sc.id = q.section 
  INNER JOIN chapters AS c ON c.id = q.chapter
  INNER JOIN paragraphs AS p ON p.id = q.paragraph
WHERE (q.author_id=1) 
ORDER BY  q.id asc 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

If you try to run that against MySQL directly, what happens?

Comment: Your result: http://screencast.com/t/hG2I9AUrboDc  My result: http://screencast.com/t/aFf27Scr And db structure  http://i.stack.imgur.com/45IOR.png

Comment: Sorry - superfluous comma.  Edited now - try again?

Comment: Tried. Same result as mine:))

Comment: Uhhhh...  you said that the subject that's coming back is the subject field in the question table, right?  Based on your DB structure, you were incorrect.  The subject field in the question table is an integer, but the subject field in the results in screencast.com/t/aFf27Scr is a string.

Comment: I want to get string `subjects.subject` column by it's id - subjects.id which located in `questions.subject`

Comment: Well, why didn't you say so?  Simply change sb.subject to q.subject in the list of columns the query returns.  That'll get you an integer ID just like the other columns in your query.  Then, mark my answer as correct ;-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11201/discussion-between-epic-syntax-and-benjamin-cox)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the query in your question is fine, but still to dig it out use this statement instead and see what comes up in **subjects_subject** column:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS q.id, q.question, sb.subject as subjects_subject, c.chapter, sc.section, p.paragraph 
FROM questions AS q
     , subjects AS sb
     , sections AS sc
     , chapters AS c
     , paragraphs AS p 
WHERE (sb.id=q.subject AND c.id=q.chapter AND sc.id=q.section AND p.id=q.paragraph) AND (q.author_id=1) 
ORDER BY  q.id asc 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

Comment: I provided subject as example. Actually all three  sections AS sc, chapters AS c, paragraphs AS p are not working. I'm getting only subject.

Comment: @epic_syntax - That's part of the problem. You are not posting your actual statement but part of it in where you think the problem is.

Comment: @epic_syntax then the problem is not in the query... Some thing else is wrong... can you describe your db structure or that php function you are talking about..??